# Grohe Ladylux kitchen faucet leaking underneath

Tags: repair

My Grohe Ladylux kitchen faucet is running significant water down the hoses from the housing underneath the counter.  Is changing out the cartridge going to solve this problem, or what will help?

Comment: Can you post a picture? Which hoses, the supply hoses (from the shutoff valves to the faucet knobs) or the spray hose (from the faucet knobs to the sink sprayer)? Have you tried just tightening the fittings yet?

Comment: we are sorry you are having issues with the Ladylux kitchen faucet. If you still need assistance please email us at Us-customerservice@grohe.com and ask for Deidrea Hubeck our customer service supervisor. She will be happy to help you. Thanks,
GROHE

Answer (score 0):

If it's leaking where the hose meets the pull-out faucet head you unscrew the hose from the handle and there's an o-ring you can replace. Any plumbing supply shop that deals with Grohe should have it.

Before fitting the new o-ring make sure the installation area is clean and apply an o-ring compatible grease to all contact areas so the new o-ring doesn't bind up or get torn when installing it.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same faucet installed a month ago... worked great for awhile then same leaking occurred up under faucet housing. We narrowed it down to the cold water side in housing, and it doesn’t leak continually which made it hard to locate. We are replacing this faucet with a different brand!

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced my Grohe Ladylux spray head on a faucet installed in 2003 because the spray function failed and cannot be repaired.  I ordered the Grohe o-ring required for the new head after reading the old o-ring won't prevent leaking at the head connection to the pull-out line, but it will take longer to arrive. After trials with  both heads, I learned the old o-ring won't work with the new spray head because it requires a fatter o-ring of the same diameter. I had one from an inexpensive generic faucet repair kit that fit perfectly and gave me a nice, tight, waterproof connection. The construction of the old and new spray heads is enough different that you need this kind of remedy for a new Grohe spray head, but it doesn't have to be a Grohe washer. (It has nothing to do with the old o-ring being compressed.  Mine functioned perfectly with the old spray head.  I believe it is all about a change in manufacturing specs.)